# Hash Function for a 7 digits int

Tags: c++, hashtable, hash-function

I'm new to hash tables and functions, so I apologize in advance if I got anything wrong.

I'm trying to create a hash table in C++ for a list of about 100k entries comprised of a 7 digit number.
The thing is, I got stuck while trying to figure out what hash function to use.

When using %100000 I got ~65k unique keys, while there are ~90k unique entries. Which means that about 1/3 of the data will have collisions.

Is this a good hash function to use? Or is there a better function to use in that case in order to have less collisions?
What size should my table be?

Thanks again!

Edit-
The entries are numbers between 1 and 2 mil.
Is it possible to use the number itself as the key? Or should keys for hash table always start at 0?

Comment: with `%100000` any number `>100000`  is mapped to something `<100000`. Its just maths to see how many collisions there are. Actually I'd expect much more

Comment: Why do you need a hash function at all when you already have a 7-digit number? Just use that.

Comment: If I recall correctly then you get less collisions if your modulus is a prime number – can anyone confirm?

Comment: @Aconcagua not really. The bigger the modulus is, the smaller number of collisions (assuming the input set is bounded), regardless of whether these are prime or not. In particular if the input set is in range [0,n) then number of collisions modulo n is 0. While for any prime smaller than n is positive.

Comment: *'Or should keys for hash table always start at 0?'* – well, I'd assume the underlying memory of your hash table is an array – and the indices of these start with 0. If now your numbers are indeed *guaranteed* to be within 1 M and 2 M then you simply might subtract 1 M to bring the numbers in appropriate range – provided your array has 1 M entries, of course...

Comment: @super sorry, but I don't understand how and why should I use the number itself is the key. Sure, it would be most efficient in terms of collision and speed, but wouldn't that mean that the size of the table would be much bigger? Given that the biggest number is 2mil while there are only 100k numbers.

Comment: @wimakog1 I'm confused. Are you actually implementing your own hash table? Why don't you use std::unordered_set or std::unordered_map and be done with? Those data structures solve all of your issues, you just use numbers as keys, and let them take care of nasty details like memory layout, resizing and collision avoidance.

Comment: @Aconcagua If I substract 1M from each number I would get a table size of 1M. Which is x10 bigger than the actual number of entries. Is that proper size for a hash table?

Comment: @freakish I just need the data to be sorted inside a hash table. If I use std::unordered_set or std::unordered_map will the dataset be a hash table? Sorry, but it's the first time I've heard of these, will look them up right away. Thanks!
Also, the items I'm trying to fit into the hash table are actually objects with some variables, whereas the number I'm refering to is just the first (and most important) of those variables. Would that still work?

Comment: Is the number unique for each entry? E.g. look here for unordered_map https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63417810/unordered-map-with-custom-hash-function-and-comparison-predicate-gives-compilati Is your key the number or the whole object? Do you want to retrieve something or just test, whether it is in your hash table?

Comment: @Sebastian The number isn't unique. I'll try to explain a bit better- the number is the ID of an object which has additional values. What I need to do is sort the objects in a hash table based on their number, so I can add new entries or update existing ones.
In ~100k objects there are ~90k unique numbers.

Comment: @wimakog1 so you have objects, each having a numeric key, and that key is not necessarily unique. In that case you can use std::unordered_map with int (or whatever numeric type you use) as key and std::vector<yourObjectType> for values. But you also said that you need to sort them, so which one is it? Because if you just want to sort them, then apply std::sort and forget about hash maps.

Comment: Both unordered set and map use a hashing algorithm internally. Most convenient way for you might be a `std::map<IdType, ObjectType>`, however you store the id twice then – which you could avoid by `std::set<ObjectType>` where you'd yet need to specialise `std::hash` and `std::equal_to` for your object type. Alternatively you can provide a custom hasher type to be used as second template parameter and implement `operator==` for your type.

Comment: @freakish I don't need to sort them, just to put them inside a hash table so I can add new entries and update the other values of repeating IDs, and ultimately print all the aggregated data for each ID. The requirement is to make use of hash tables though. 
Again sorry if it's a bit all over the place, I'm new to the concept of hash tables.

Comment: The id is the (not unique) number and you want to be able to list all objects for certain ids? Then a map from id to vector/set of objects?

Comment: Please describe, in what way you want to aggregate? Just have a list or combining the objects like doing a sum? Can you model this aggregation as class type? With a function to combine another object? Then you could use this class with a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library comes with two types internally using a hash table: `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set`.

As your key type is an integral type you get a hash table pretty conveniently by `std::unordered_map<YourIdType, YourDataType`. You can easily access the data via `theMap[someId]`, but be aware that if the key is not found a new object is created! If that's not desired you'd rather use `theMap.find(someId)`, which returns an iterator.

The drawback, though, is that you store the id twice then (internally as a `std::pair<YourIdType, YourDataType>`). You can avoid that by using a `std::unordered_set`. To be able to do so, though, you need to specialise `std::hash` and `std::equal_to` for your type:

```
namespace std // you are not allowed to add to – with exception of specialisations
{
template<>
struct hash<YourDataType>
{
    size_t operator()(YourDataType const& object) const
    {
        return hash<YourIdType>()(object.id);
    }
};

// analogously equal_to with appropriate comparisons, possibly by
// comparing the object's addresses
```

Alternatively you can provide a custom hasher type (with C++20 that can even be a lambda packed into `decltype`) to the set as second template parameter and just implement `operator==` for your object type, or provide a custom equality comparer type if you need it to compare differently than the operator, maybe like:

```
// C++20 required:
using YourMapType = std::set
<
    YourDataType,
    decltype
    (
        [](YourDataType const& object)
        { return std::hash<YourIdType>()(object.id); }
    ),
    decltype
    (
        [](YourDataType const& o1, YourDataType const& o2)
        { return &o1 == &o2; } // TODO: comparisons as you need! 
    )
>;
// alternatively create custom types with appropriate operator() implementations
```

Drawback here is – apart from additional complexity for the specialisations – that you cannot lookup objects by the id only, instead you need a complete object of your data type.

So which one is more appropriate/suitable? That depends on your concrete requirements...